# launch a second installer from a custom action installer class

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a WinForms application that requires some configuration which I do at install time using a custom installer.

We have also created a web service which is installed from a separate msi.

I'd like to have a radio button selection allowing the installer to run just the client installer or the client and service installer.

Creating the custom action for the radio button is simple enough ([Example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x23561f.aspx))

**So to my questions:**

- Should I include the web service files into the client installer or
  execute the web service msi?
- Some of the parameters used by the client install are required in the
  web install. If I launch the separate msi, can I pass these values
  across without the user having to enter the data twice?
- If I include the web service, how do I go about combining client and 
  web installations?

**EDIT:**
Things I've tried:

I have tried creating a web installer and creating the directory structure for the client executable but this then causes a permissions error (probably because I'm installing to the Program Files folder). I suspect this will be the same issue if I try a client installer and manually create the directory structure under inetpub for the web service.

If I include the built output from the web service installer, I can not access it from the Custom Actions Editor screen and therefore can't apply the conditional launch.

It's starting to look like I will need to extend the custom installer class that I currently use to launch the msi as a shell command but this doesn't seem like the correct way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  Windows Installer implements a mutex that prevents this.   The only way you'll automate the installation of both of those MSI's is through the use of a bootstrapper / chainer.